# WRAPCOLS and WRAPROWS functions to change table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, adjustable-array

In EXCEL, I would like to change the array of a two columns table (A1:A91;B1:B91) to a 13 X 7 table as follows, by removing the "Turnover" text and replacing the cells with the turnover quantity.
[image]

I would like to use some functions such as WRAPCOLS, CHOOSEROWS and TOROW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell `D1` put the following formula:

```
=LET(rng, A1:B26, colA, INDEX(rng,,1), colB, INDEX(rng,,2),
 values, FILTER(colB, colB<>"Turnover"),
 codes, FILTER(colA, colB="Turnover"),
 months, TEXT(EDATE(1, SEQUENCE(1,12,0)),"mmm"),
 matrix, WRAPROWS(values, 12), 
 VSTACK(HSTACK("",months), HSTACK(codes, matrix))
)
```

and here is the output:
[image: Sample excel file]

It is just to select conveniently the information we need from the input data to generate it in the format we want. The `months` since they are all the same we took: `1`, i.e. `1/1/1900` and format it via `TEXT` as `mmm`. If you need the `months` for a given year *as dates data type* and format in Excel as `mmmm`. Then you can use one of the following options:

- Use the formula: `EDATE(x, SEQUENCE(1,12,0))`, where `x` represents any date corresponding to January of a given year or use `A2` if it is a date in previous formula.
- Use the formula: `TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(colA, colB<>"Turnover")))`.

Comment: wow, thank you enormous

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisGila, both solutions (mine and @Ike) are quite similar, I just posted mine without realizing that he posted one already. I do a wrap to 12 instead of 2, so it avoids using `TRANSPOSE` and I prefer to define names so it is easier to read the formula. I would say that is the only significant difference. I just upvoted his solution to give him credit for his approach too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,A1:B26,
dOnly,FILTER(d,INDEX(d,,2)<>"Turnover"),
years,UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(d,,1),INDEX(d,,2) = "Turnover")),
months,UNIQUE(INDEX(dOnly,,1)),
HSTACK(VSTACK({""},years),VSTACK(TRANSPOSE(months),WRAPROWS(INDEX(dOnly,,2),ROWS(months)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach:

```
=LET(s, SEQUENCE(,13,0),
     x, IF(s,TEXT(s*28,"mmm"),""),
     y, TOCOL(IFS(ISERR(DAY(1&A1:A91)),A1:A91),2),
VSTACK(x,
       HSTACK(y,
              WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B1:B91,1),12))))
```

[image]